# Xcode gives error for everything I write

Tags: swift, xcode

I have been searching for a solution for two days but could not find anything on web.
I was working on a project and then instantly I was not able to declare anything new or iterate anything older that I wrote. I tried opening new project and start again but it was there again. You can see in the photo that it does need declaration for already declared variables such as cool and hype. 
Now I am not able to work on any project.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var cool: Int = 2
    var hype: Int = 2

    hype = 2 + cool

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set up the location manager here.
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    // ...
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, instead of posting a screenshot, please copy and paste your code into your question and include the errors. A screenshot can be good to show your particular case since you have quit a few problems with the code, however, it is useful to be able to copy and adjust the code ourselves to help you.

Comment: Copy all of your code, because I think just one } missing

Comment: It's really hard to tell what's going wrong from a screen-shot. You might have to post your project to a public git repo and post the link here.

Comment: All the errors are gone after a day without me doing anything.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use of undeclared type 'CLLocationManageDelegate'

   - This is because you haven't imported the CoreLocation module
   - Add the line `import CoreLocation` above the `import UIKit`
2. You can't perform the assignment of `hype` in that scope, try moving it into `viewDidLoad`
3. You must declare a location manager variable and initialize one:

   - Add the line `var locationManager = CLLocationManager()` above your other vars.

---

```
import CoreLocation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    var cool: Int = 2
    var hype: Int = 2

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        hype = 2 + cool

        // Set up the location manager here.
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, all your errors are totally generic, caused by syntax and other mistakes.

- It should be `CLLocationManager` needs to be imported.

  - This produces errors in declaration and other places depending on it.
- Variables can be declared but not manipulated outside a function on the top level of a class.
- The variable `locationManager` has not been defined previously